# Timestamp to Date in appscript

Tags: google-apps-script

I've got a timestamp (e.g 1545004800000), and I'm trying to convert it to a Date object in Google Appscript, however, `new Date(1545004800000)` doesn't work as it would in Javascript.

How can I do that in Google Appscript?

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Comment: Or What made you presumptively conclude that it didn't work?

Comment: I was getting a 1970 Date, I guess I had a problem with the timestamp order of magnitude (despite having logged the exact value that I put here) as I couldn't reproduce on a plain project.

Comment: Arre you sure @angrykoala? This works for me too. Here's an interesting context component maybe; it took me a bit to figure out how to convert epoch milliseconds from the appscript datepicker to a humanly readable format. I have a form with a datepicker widget named 'Date' and from within the form submission handler:

function submitForm(e) {
   var res = e['formInput'];
   var dateObj = new Date(res['Date']['msSinceEpoch']);
   var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(dateObj, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
   ...

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
var dateObj = new Date(1545004800000);
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(dateObj, "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```